# How to assert the value of an input element with assert_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Given this HTML in the view:

```
<form id="new_merchant_user" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div id='legend'>
       <legend>Recover Pasword</legend>
     </div>
     <input id="merchant_user_email" name="merchant_user[email]" type="text" value="" />
     <input class="btn btn-success" name="commit" type="submit" value="Send Reset Instructions" />

   </fieldset>
</form>
```

How do I select the value of the button with assert_select?
I try

```
assert_select 'form input[type=submit]', "Send Reset Instructions"
```

but its failing with

```
<Send Reset Instructions> expected but was
<>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Basically, selecting nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

In your case use:

```
assert_select 'form input[type=submit][value=Send Reset Instructions]'
```

As value is an attribute not the text within a html tag.

Comment: I found I needed to surround "Send Reset Instructions" with double quotes otherwise it was flagged as an invalid CSS selector.

Comment: I think you are using Rails 4. Because this syntax works fine with Rails 3 and ruby 2. But in Rails 4 and above and ruby 2.1 and above it does say "Invalid CSS selector".

Answer (score 2):

If you're using capybara you can try something like [click_button](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions%3aclick_button), [submit](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/RackTest/Form%3asubmit) or [click_on](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions%3aclick_link_or_button).

Comment: I'm not using capybara.